# how to change the value of a field based on a quantity field and a select box

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to update the value of a field based on a select box select option and the quantity of few quantity fields, it works fine for the first field but it wouldn't work for the rest.

this is the link to the site is http://www.snappy-pizza.net/pizza1c.php

if you choose a pizza for the first time and add toppings to it, the value of the updated price field will increase as expected, now if you change your pizza with the same toppings only the first topping will be added to the price and not the other ones.

```
  <input name="update_price" type="text" id="update_price" value="" size="8" maxlength="8" />


  <form>
                <select name="select" id="select">
                  <option>Select your pizza</option>
                  <option value="6.65">NY, 10&quot;, £6.65</option>
                  <option value="8.95">NY, 12&quot;, £8.95</option>
                  <option value="11.95">NY, 16&quot;, £11.95</option>
                  <option value="3.45">Chicago, 7&quot;, £3.45</option>
                  <option value="6.65">Chicago, 10&quot;, £6.65</option>
                  <option value="8.95">Chicago, 12&quot;, £8.95</option>
                  <option value="11.95">Chicago, 16&quot;, £11.95</option>
                  <option value="19.95">Chicago, Beast 24&quot; x 18&quot;, £19.95</option>
                 </select>
         </form>


       <form>
         <tr>
            <td> 

            <span class="descriptionsPizza">EXTRA CHEESE</span>
            <input name="minus1" type="button" class="button minus" id="minus1" value=" - " />
            <input name="textfield1" type="text" id="textfield1" class="valfield" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0" />
            <input name="add1" type="button" class="button add" id="add1" value=" + " />
            </td>

            <td>
            <span class="descriptionsPizza">HAM</span>    
            <input name="minus2" type="button" class="button minus" id="minus2" value=" - " />
            <input class="valfield" name="textfield2" type="text" id="textfield2" size="2" maxlength="2" value="0"/>
            <input name="add2" type="button" class="button add" id="add2" value=" + " />
            </td>
            </tr>




           //function to change the quantity field by pressing the + and - buttons
   $(function()
    {
      topping_price = 1;
      $(".add").click(function(){
     var newQty =+($(this).siblings(".valfield").val()) + 1;
     $(this).siblings(".valfield").val(newQty);

 current_price =+($('input[name=update_price]').val() );
 $('input[name=update_price]').val(topping_price + current_price);
  });

 $(".minus").click(function(){
 var newQty = +($(this).siblings(".valfield").val()) - 1;
 if(newQty < 0)newQty = 0;
 $(this).siblings(".valfield").val(newQty);

var current_price =+($('input[name=update_price]').val() );
$('input[name=update_price]').val(current_price - topping_price);
});
```

});

```
  //function to get the value and text of the selected select box and insert them into hidden fields.
 $(function()
  {
$('#select').change( function() {
    $('input[name=my-item-name]').val( $("#select :selected").text() );
    $('input[name=my-item-price]').val( $("#select").val() );

    $(".add").each(function() {
        //gets the value of the selected box (i.e.price) and insert it into the updated price field.
        var new_qty =+ ($(".add").siblings(".valfield").val() );
        var pizza_price =+ ($("#select :selected").val() );
        $('input[name=update_price]').val((new_qty * topping_price) + pizza_price);
    });
});
```

});

any help would be appreciated..

Comment: If you want people to keep helping you out then I would go back and mark answers to your previous questions. P.S you get points for this also.

Comment: ok, sorry I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have improved your jquery.js file. This version is much cleaner.

```
// JavaScript Document

var toppingPrice = 1;

//function to get the value and text of the selected select box and insert them into hidden fields.  
var updateTotalPrice = function() {
  var pizzaPrice = parseFloat($("#select").val());
  var quantity = 0;
  $(".add").each(function() {
    quantity = quantity + parseInt($(this).siblings(".valfield").val(), 10);
  });
  $('#update_price').val((quantity * toppingPrice) + pizzaPrice);
}

$(function()
{
  //functions to change the quantity field by pressing the + and - buttons
  // add buttons
  $(".add").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var quantity = parseInt($this.siblings(".valfield").val(), 10) + 1;
    $(this).siblings(".valfield").val(quantity);

    updateTotalPrice();
  });

  // minus buttons
  $(".minus").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var quantity = parseInt($this.siblings(".valfield").val(), 10) - 1;
    if(quantity < 0) quantity = 0;
    $(this).siblings(".valfield").val(quantity);

    updateTotalPrice();
  });

  // selectbox
  $('#select').change(function() {
    updateTotalPrice();
  });

  //function to generate a random number and insert them to the item id hidden field
  $('input[name=my-add-button]').click(function() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9000) + 100);
    $('input[name=my-item-id]').val(randomNumber);
  });
});
```

Comment: one more question! I need to insert the value of text of the select box and the toppings text into a hidden field for the shopping cart to use.I can get the text of the select box but how can I get the toppings text as well and insert both of them in the hidden field.

thanks

Comment: something like if the quantity of the topping is greater than zero get the the quantity and text of the topping and add them into the hidden field with the text of the select box.

Comment: You can wrap toppings in a form element and give them proper names. After that you can use serialize method for getting toppings data. Like: var toppingsData = $("#toppingsForm").serialize();

Comment: sorry to keep bothering you,I'm a bit confused,I got proper names for the form elements, and if I serialize the form, like var toppings_data = $("#toppings").serialize;  how can I get to the text of the toppings(i.e.extra cheese and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$(function() {
  $('#select').change(function() {
    var pizza_price = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var new_qty = 0;
    $(".add").each(function() {
      new_qty = new_qty + parseInt($(this).siblings(".valfield").val(), 10);
    });
    $('#update_price').val((new_qty * topping_price) + pizza_price);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply but the same problem still exist, it works fine for the first time(when you choose pizza and add toppings to it), but with the same toppings selected if you choose a different pizza it only adds the first topping to it not the second and third.

Comment: I have changed your function a bit and tested on your page. Now it's working like a charm. Try yourself :)

Comment: Thank you so much,would you be kind enough and explain what was wrong with it.
Thanks

Comment: $(".add") brings you all elements with class .add. you should use $(this) when it's in the iteration.